# Is this a legitimate way to prove $0!=1$?

Tags: factorial, solution-verification

if $n$ is any integer, we find that $\dfrac{n!/(n+1)}{(n-1)!/n}$ is $\dfrac{n^2}{n+1}$ through simplification. By putting in $n = 1$, we find that $\dfrac{1/2}{0!} = \dfrac{1}{2}$. Thus, we get $0! = 1$. Is this way of proving correct?

Comment: No, because you're inherently assuming that $0! \neq 1$.

Comment: We start with a definition of $n!$ for $n$ a positive integer. We notice that $n!=n\times(n-1)!$. So to make that hold for $n=1$ we need $0!=1$. That is essentially what you are saying. Yes. That is a useful extension of the definition. It is not a "proof".

Comment: @Clement Yung,  you probably meant $0!\neq 0$.

Comment: @Ansar yes, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your "*proof*", $n!$ is only defined when $n≧１$. So,
 $\frac{n!/（n+1)}{(n-1)!/n} $   is defined only when $n-1≧１i.e. n≧２$.

So you **cannot** put $n＝１$ into your identical equation.

If you want to **define**  $0!$ naturally , natural requirement shall be $n!＝n\cdot（n-1)!$,take n＝１,then we have no choice but to define $0!＝1$.
This is a standard definition of $n!（n≧０,n∈\mathbb{Z}）$ but not a *proof* of  $0!＝１$.

Answer (score 0):

No because $$\dfrac{n!/(n+1)}{(n-1)!/n} = \frac {n^2}{n+1}$$ only if $n\not = 1$

You are using it for $n=1$ as well.